# EJB 3.1 Stateful and CDI Scope Conversation

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a `@Stateful` EJB annotated as `@ConversationScoped`. The client (JSF) makes a request to my EJB which: starts the conversation - `conversation.begin()`, do something and shows the response to the client.

The client then makes another request, the EJB does something and closes the conversation - `conversation.end()`.

Is the `@Stateful` EJB removed after the conversation end? Or do I have to explicitly call `@Remove`?

Answer (score 3):

The CDI specs say that the scoped EJBs are automatically created and destroyed when the scope is created or destroyed. The same is true for the Conversation scope. So, you should not try to call a @Remove method.

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/concepts.html#d0e1066